# Expire time express and redis session

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I'm using express and redis to keep the session live on my system. I having some problems to set the maxAge on the sessionCookie. By the default I read that is 24hrs, but that's a long time to keep it live. I would like to set like 30 min and then logout the user, I changed for 1min to see if it works but nothing happens, the user still logged.

This is my session function:

```
module.exports.initSession = function(app, db) {
  app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 30*10000,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: Boolean(process.env.ssl) || true
    },
    key: config.sessionKey,
    store: new RedisStore({
      host: config.redis.host || 'localhost',
      port: config.redis.port || 6379,
      db: config.redis.database || 0,
      pass: config.redis.password || ''
    })
  }));
};
```

I also tried using ttl instead of maxAge but I get the same result. What could it be?

EDITED:

I using [SEAN.JS](https://github.com/seanjs-stack/seanjs/) and the files that content the session are this two:
[express.js](https://github.com/seanjs-stack/seanjs/blob/master/config/lib/express.js) and [default](https://github.com/seanjs-stack/seanjs/blob/master/config/env/default.js) environment.

Comment: if you want it to be 30min, you have to set it to 1000*60*30, not 10000*30 = 5min. Plus, im not sure but i think you have to initialize cookie parser before you set your session if you want to use cookie based, var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); app.use(cookieParser())

Comment: @FluffyNights `cookie-parser` is no longer needed, [see the notes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessionoptions).

Comment: I edited my question to show you which framework I'm using

Comment: As long as a session gets modified during a request, it will not expire. The `maxAge` value is basically used for an _idle_ timer: if the session hasn't been modified at all for `maxAge` ms, the session will expire. So if you're reloading the page waiting for the expiry, the session will probably be updated each time and the timer reset.

Comment: @robertklep But still, If I close the tab and wait for the time pass, the session still there, I don't know what I'm not doing for this works properly. :/

Comment: It might be a SEAN.JS bug/feature, I'm not familiar with that framework. The configuration of the session middleware looks okay (aside from the `maxAge` setting, as @FluffyNights already pointed out, but that's a minor thing).

Comment: same issue. how did you solve that?

Comment: @AliSherafat I didn't solve it yet. I set the expiration time, but it does not logout from the system, I have to do it manually. If you find something let me know.

Answer (score 5):

This is my configuration for sessions and it works.
I set the expiration time to 5 seconds for testing purposes.

```
app.use(session({
        store: new redisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        client: redisClient,
        ttl: 5 // in seconds
    }),
    secret: 'this is secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    // cookie: {maxAge: 5000}
}));
```

I set `maxAge` and it didn't work and when i set `ttl` it worked.

**Note:** I tested and found out that `ttl` is in second but maxAge is in milli seconds! (kinda weird)

you can log session data using a middleware like below to see if a passport object exists or not, if there is no passport object in sesssion data, user is logged out.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('session:\n', req.session);
    next();
});
```

Comment: I actually have `cookie : {maxAge: }` and works the same way that you use the ttl. The session expires but It keep logged on the system and I have to logout manually.

Comment: @Ellebkey are you sure that you handle login system correctly? I use `passport` and it works. log all the session data using a middleware to see the auth date exists in session or not.

Comment: This is how the serialize works on the sean stack [here] (https://github.com/seanjs-stack/seanjs/blob/master/modules/users/server/config/user.server.config.js)

Comment: It's ok, try to log all session data and see if a passport object exists in session if so, you are not logged out. and also delete `cookie : {maxAge: }` and set only `ttl` to a small number like  3 seconds and see if it works and deletes passport object from session data or not.

Answer (score 0):

`cookie: {maxAge: 5000}` will expire the cookie of the client after 5 seconds and not the session stored in **REDIS**.
If you want to expire a session in the RedisStore use the **ttl** option as [Ali Sherafat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5160077/ali-sherafat) mentioned.